# How to work with memory mapped files when loading multiple large images

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

I have many georeferenced images of the US in png and tiff format. There are about 12 that I want to use. Each image is about 60mb and the resolution is about 18000*12000 pixels. I am trying to create a windows forms application that loads all of the images to create a map. (check out the link below--top pic).The program also has zoom/pan capability. I have tried loading about 4 images and the application gets really slow and it even crashes many times. So I want to know if I could use memory mapped files (or any other way). What I want to do is load only the portion of the images that is visible and not all of the images. When you zoom or pan, only the visible map part should load. I want to use memory mapped files for this but don't know where to start.

[What I am trying to create](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/vfr/assets/img/FAA_WAC_index.jpg)

Comment: You might want to look in to breaking up the images in to smaller lower resolution tiles for multiple zoom levels, then only load the lower resolution tiles for the zoom level you are at that is displayed on screen. This is what most mapping interfaces do. It will take up more disk space but use much less RAM.

Comment: Oh ok. So if I have say 10 zoom levels, then I would need to break the image up into 10 different ones?So I don't use memory mapped files right? I can just store the images in a list. But I guess the problem would still be there if someone zooms in all the way

Comment: No, you break the image up in to 100's or 1000's per zoom level but each image would be something small like 200x200 px in size. You then load into memory the 20 or so tiles that are on screen, when a user moves their view or changes zoom level you release the memory to the not shown images and load up the new shown ones. Look at google maps as you zoom out very quickly, [you can see the tileing method I am trying to explain at work](http://i.stack.imgur.com/R5PNM.png).

Comment: No, you lower the resolution on the image. Take a look at [this blog post](http://blog.mikecouturier.com/2011/07/create-zoomable-images-using-google.html) it explains a little bit on how to use Goolge maps for your own tile images. In the article it has source code for a program that will split up your images in to tiles.

Comment: Thanks, I am actually using this library called GMap.Net which uses google maps. Let me give you an example and you tell me if I understand it. Say I have an image 300x300 px(just for the sake of this eg) and I want 3 zoom levels and 9 tiles to show. For level1: 9 tiles and 100px each tile, level2:9 tiles and 66px each tile, level3: 9 tiles and 33px each tile. Level 3 would be zooming out all the way. Would it work this way but for a very large image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our conversation in messages is getting a little long so I will turn this in to an answer.

Don't use memory mapped files, use a tiled map system.

For now I am just going to deal with a single 18000*12000 image but you can extend this logic to the multiple images you have. What you are going to do is you need to break it up in in to smaller lower resolution chunks to show to the user at a given time.

So say you have 3 zoom levels 100%, 66%, and 33%. 100% would be the native resolution.

So for 100% we break the image up in to smaller 250x250px images, so now you have 3,456 small 250x250 images (72 images across by 48 images down).

For the 66% you either use a different source image to represent that "zoom level" (for example you might not show smaller roads on a map) or you can decrease the size of your original image. Lets say you decrease the image, you use a paint program to lower the resolution of your source image to 12000x8000, we once again break the image up in to smaller 250x250px images, so now you have 1,536 small 250x250 images (48 images across by 32 images down).

We repeat the process again for 33% lower the resolution of your source image to 6000x4000, we once again break the image up in to smaller 250x250px images, so now you have 384 small 250x250 images (24 images across by 16 images down).

So in your database you keep the 5,376 images you generated (3,456 + 1,536 + 384) Say the user has a useable screen resolution of 1920x1080, you would load 40 of the 250x250 tiles in memory (8 images across by 5 images down) for the appropriate zoom level and show them on screen. If your user pans or change zoom levels new tiles load and you let old tiles unload so you only need to keep 40 250x250 images in memory at any given time.

Comment: OK makes a lot of sense. Some questions though: why do we need to decrease the size of the images? I mean we are going to break the images into 250x250 px for all zoom levels. Also, if I have a winforms app and the visual window (where the map shows) is about 1000px x 500px, would that be the screen res or the actual monitor res. In that case, I would need to show only 4x2 tiles for all zoom levels right?

Comment: We break it down to 250x250 so each image does not cause a heavy load in processing. you deal with a few dozen 1kb images instead of 1 60mb image. As for the resolution, yes 4x2 would sound about right. Just a fyi GMap.net should be doing all of the displaying logic and how many should be on the screen for you.

Comment: when I store the images in the database, what information should I store with them. Like the xy coordinates of the images on the map? Also when fetching the images from the database, how would I know which ones to fetch? I mean I will need to fetch 8 images but which ones?

Comment: That is usually determined by the library you use to display them (gmap.net in your case, check the documentation, I was just explaining how it works)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to have to comment on this one. I immediate saw a red flag when the answer went into "zoom levels". From a programmer's viewpoint this is a lazy method that avoids dealing with additional image calculations, but from the user's perspective it's a pretty poor one if they want a continuous range for zooming. Google does it for speed and bandwidth which is fine for the specific application. The irony here is I came to this thread because I have a map already broken up into tiles (625 1009x1009!) where all I want to do is pan. It's a pain when the only solution does not even touch the original question.

Edit: If a moderator sees this please convert this to a comment. I don't know how it became an answer.

Comment: what if i want to have only a certain number of zoom levels?

Comment: Again, look at the title of your question. It's about LOADING the images using memory mapping. If you have only a certain number of zoom levels that's another issue and the proffered solution is correct. Of course the "solution" isn't about the question at all. It breaks down to "Don't do that; do this instead using an external program to preprocess the image.".  Of course in the body of your question you allowed for this. But it sucks for those actually looking for help with the original question.